# unable to update maven configuration

Tags: maven

I have to 2 projects of which I am unable to update the maven configuration through Eclipse.
It says "Path must include project and resource name: /cims-ear" and "Path must include project and resource name: /cimsJob-ear"

(cims-ear and cimsJob-ear are the project names btw)

Does someone has an idea what could cause this because I have no clue at all.

I have these modules in my pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>functional-test/cims-job</module>
    <module>functional-test/cims</module>
    <module>modules/cims-commonEjb</module>
    <module>modules/cims-commonClient</module>
    <module>modules/cims-ejb</module>
    <module>modules/cims-ejb3</module>
    <module>modules/cims-digichambers</module>
    <module>modules/cims-ejbClient</module>
    <module>modules/mst-errorhandling</module>
    <module>modules/mst-errorhandling-client</module>                
    <module>modules/cims-web</module>                
    <module>modules/cims-job</module>
    <module>modules/cims-jobWeb</module>               
    <module>applications/cims-ear</module>               
    <module>applications/cims-jobEar</module>    
</modules>
```

The directory structure is:

```
cims
-->applications
----->cims-ear
----->cims-jobEar
-->modules
----->...all the modules
-->functional tests
----->...all functional tests
```

Thanks

Comment: does your pom define modules?

Comment: can you post the relevant pom snippet and the directory structure?

Comment: added pom and dir structure in my question :D

Comment: What are in the 'application' directories?  Are those created by your build process?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with UNC path under Windows, I added a Network drive on this UNC path and boom it works.